# Encrypt Lightning event invite mails with pgp

Tags: encryption, email, pgp

I use Thunderbirds/Icedoves [Lightning add-on](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/projects/calendar/) to manage my calendar, tasks and notes.

When creating an event I can add attendees and send invitations to them, but they won't use their public pgp keys to encrypt the invitation.

How can I force the invitations to be encrypted?

[image: Sample event creating with invitation]

***edit***:
as suggested by @schroeder, I've asked the question on the mozilla support page.
For anyone interested, here's the [link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1033737).

Comment: This is a product-specific configuration question. You'd find better help on other sites.